# Make unique colume in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have table which has a duplicate data.

This is my Now table

```
Id  Name
1   shahin Zen
2   shahin Zen & Aaron Henley
3   Fred Sayz feat. Antonia Lucas
4   Fred Sayz feat. Lawrence Alexander
5   Fred Sayz feat. Sibel
```

Note: I can not use distinct beacuse name has not fully match.

I want to make a table form this table like,

```
ID  Name
1   shahin
2   Fred
```

Please anyone solved this kind of problem.

Thanks advance

Comment: Is the requirement to just list the first name?

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to get distinct first words of the rows:

```
select distinct substring(Name, 0, charindex(' ', Name, 0))
from myTable
```

you can also add a check for the rows that contains space character by adding a where clause:

```
where charindex(' ', myTable, 0) > 0
```

Comment: you're welcome, but please mark correct answers if you benefit from them :)

Comment: @Noxthron upvoting yours because it helped the OP, but you can compensate for the lack of a space by appending one to the varchar you're CharIndexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the first names, try this:

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)) 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for those records that don't have a space...

```
Select  Distinct Left(name,CharIndex(' ',name+' '))
From    myTable
```